# Symfony dates are incorrect

Tags: mongodb, date, symfony, timezone

I'm using Symfony and MongoDB.

- I submit a form with: name="pupil[dateOfBirth]" -> 17-09-1985
- And MongoDB stores it "a day earlier" as: 1985-09-16T22:00:00.000Z

How can i be sure mongo stores the right dates?
I used the BSON-type Date (9) in MongoDB

Answer (score 1):

Doctrine will stored DateTimes in [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

Given the time stored, this means your PHP timezone is 2 hours ahead of UTC, so 17th September 1985 becomes 16th September 1985 at 10pm. The `Z` at the end indicates the timezone, being UTC.

When you get the datetime value from Mongo, it should be converted back to 17th September 1985 at midnight.

There may be a way to store the DateTime values in Mongo as 1985-09-17T00:00:00.000+02:00

Comment: @MathiasDewelde interesting, I thought it might be smart enough to use PHP's date.timezone setting to convert it back... Perhaps you could explicitly set the timezone setting either on storing or when retrieving...

Answer (score 0):

By explicitly setting the DateTime object to midnight and the right timezone in the Document setters, MongoDb stores it as "... 22:00:00.000Z" instead of "... 23:00:00.000Z".

```
/**
 * Set dateOfBirth
 *
 * @param Date $dateOfBirth
 * @return self
 */
 public function setDateOfBirth($dateOfBirth)
 {
     $this->dateOfBirth = $dateOfBirth->modify('midnight')->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Brussels'));
     return $this;
 }
```